# powershell cmdlet Get-Vm not displaying at the correct time

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

This is the script in it's most current form, on line 6 of the code I am trying to get it to display the current condition of the virtuals on the host.
when I run the code, it doesn't display until the very end.

It runs properly everywhere else, and it proforms the actions like I want it to. But `Get-VM` doesn't run until right before the script exits.

Is there some sort of forcing command that makes commands execute that I don't know of? I know it's probably just some stupid mistake I am not seeing.

Help is appreciated, if you need further clarification, just let me know.

```
#new-alias -Name rh -Value read-host
Get-VM
$AA = rh "Would you like to preform an action?[y/n]"
While($AA -eq "y"){
$A = rh "What would you like to do? `n save?[sa] `n start?[st] `n stop?[x] 
`n restart?[re]`n "

# blank-vm -name blank
If($A -eq "sa"){
$s = "Save"
$B = rh "Which VM would you like to $s ?[a for all]"
if($B -eq "a"){
Get-VM | Save-VM
}
else{save-vm -name "$B"}
}
If($A -eq "st"){
$s = "Start"
$B = rh "Which VM would you like to $s ?[a for all]"
if($B -eq "a"){
Get-VM | Start-VM
}
else{Start-vm -name "$B"}
}
If($A -eq "x"){
$s = "Stop"
$B = rh "Which VM would you like to $s ?[a for all]"
if($B -eq "a"){
Get-VM | stop-VM
}
else{Stop-vm -name "$B"}
}
If($A -eq "re"){
$s = "Restart"
$B = rh "Which VM would you like to $s ?[a for all]"
if($B -eq "a"){
Get-VM | restart-VM
}
else{restart-vm -name "$B"}
}
$AA = rh "Would you like to preform another action?[y/n]"
}
```

Comment: I don't even know where to start with this... You've hard coded server names into the script so whats the point in using Get-VM to offer a list at all, since the script can't cope with any servers other than the ones you hard coded. Personally, this script seems pretty pointless as everything can be done from the GUI for basic users or from the proper powershell commands for advanced users, but if you insist, either make it properly generic and remove hard coded values, or just hard code the list of server from the start.

Comment: I had intended to have Get-VM display as a current state menu. To let you know, at a glance, what vms are currently running. I would make it more generic, but I have no idea how to. The current version of this script is written with hard-coded VM names because they did not want to type the full names of the virtual machines. (because the Get-VM would not display.) I do have a slightly more generic code and I will update my post with that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the Hyper-V cmdlets and the Read/Write-Host cmdlets, e. g.

```
Get-VM
Write-Host "Test"
```

will result in first writing the string Test to the host and then outputting the result of Get-VM. Get-VMHost, Get-VMHardDisk and Get-VMSwitch have the same issue. The "standard" cmdlets like Get-Service and Get-Process are working normally, e. g.

```
Get-Service
Write-Host "Test"
```

will first outputting a list of services and then the string Test. Using the Write-Output instead of Write-Host will result in normal behavior too.

To avoid this you can convert your Get-VM output to string, e. g.:

```
Get-VM | Out-String
Write-Host "Test"
```

Other cmdlets could have the same issue

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem. So it was a problem with the Hyper-v Cmdlets, not with my script.... interesting. Thank you for sharing!